# Flutter Calendar_picker_2

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i am using calendar_picker_2 widget for date pick.

```
initialValue: [DateTime.now()]
```

This DateTime.now() showing date and time. how to remove the time. i want to show date only

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the date only as a String, use the `DateFormat format` method:

```
DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now())
```

This will display as "25/01/2023".

If you want to initialize it to the date only with zeros for time, use the `DateUtils` class:

```
DateUtils.dateOnly(DateTime.now())
```

Anyway, the `showCalendarDatePicker2Dialog` will ignore the time portion of a DateTime object, so it is safe to pass in the initial value as `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: i am using List<DateTime?> fromdate = [DateUtils.dateOnly(DateTime.now())];
  List<DateTime?> todate = [DateUtils.dateOnly(DateTime.now())];. its not working

Comment: You initial post didn't say anything about what you were trying to accomplish. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Include the whole minimally reproducible code so we can try for ourselves.